# Visual Studio Single Windows Form application Multiple Developer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am about to develop a Windows Form application using Visual Studio. I want multiple developers to work on the same project I created. However users are not at same location as me, ie they are connected in via the internet.

My question is, How can we all work on the single application concurrently and have multiple developers connected to it through the internet ?

Comment: Hire a lead developer that knows how development works. Coordinating multiple users is "software development for beginners, fist class, first day, first hour" today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use a source control tool like Subversion for example. This allows you continuously merge the code and track all the individual changes. It is often used in commercial institutions.
http://tortoisesvn.net/

There are many other paid tools you could use if you can afford.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software

Comment: Indeed the #1 choice is version control, though if you ask me I'd suggest using Git. It has a bigger community and is rising as the predominant VCS, while Subversion is mostly kept as a legacy system